# Android: Check if app is killed (swipe in recent apps) in a receiver

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

as stated in the headline, I want to know if it is possible for the BroadcastReceiver to know if the App is killed.

I tried to accomplished that with ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo:

```
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo myProcess = new ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo();
    ActivityManager.getMyMemoryState(myProcess);
    boolean isInForeground = myProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND;
    boolean isInBackground = myProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_GONE;
    boolean cached = myProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_CACHED;
    boolean perceptile = myProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_PERCEPTIBLE;
    boolean sleeping = myProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_TOP_SLEEPING;
    boolean service = myProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_SERVICE;
```

But none of those attribute can tell me if my App is still alive, they can only give me hints.

Normally I would use getRunningTask (I know it is deprecated):

```
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) mActivity.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfo = manager.getRunningTasks(100);
    for(int i = 0; i < runningTaskInfo.size(); i++) {
        ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(i).topActivity;
        if(componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(packageName)){
            return true;
        }
    }
```

But for this solution I need a activity which I dont have and I cant create (Perhaps you have an idea)?

So my question: Is it possible to know if your App is killed or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a new service like this,

```
public class FinalizingOperationsService extends Service {

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.d("FOService", "Service Started");
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.d("FOService", "Service Destroyed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
            Log.e("FOService", "Service Ends");
            // write server updation code here
            // after completing code perform stopself() to stop this service;
        }
    }
```

And define this service in manifest file like this,

```
<service android:name=".FinalizingOperationsService" android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

And then create an application class in your project and start service in this class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
    {

        @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
            super.attachBaseContext(context);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate()
        {
            super.onCreate();
            Intent itent = new Intent(this, FinalizingOperationsService.class);
            startService(itent);
        }
    }
```

**Explanation:**
onTaskRemoved() method of the service is called when application is killed or destroyed, so in this method you can perform your final operations. Hope it will help you.